# Typing Multiple Values In ag-grid Floating Filter

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

See plunker: **https://plnkr.co/edit/JEJ4j3ANQe4ZCnXI**

Pressing buttons 'Age Between 25 and 30' or 'Ireland & UK' filters the grid for multiple values.

For example, pressing button 'Age Between 25 and 30' i can see in the header filter text:

```
25-30
```

Is applied yet if i try to type this manually, it does not work.

Same for Sports column, i would have expected:

```
Rowing OR Fencing
```

to filter the grid to just the above 2 sports but again, doesnt work.

Update:

To replicate issue:

1. Open link above
2. Scroll right to display Sport column
3. Type the following: 'Rowing OR Fencing'

Grid is now empty.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Both examples of problems work fine. For the `25-30` filter, you realise you need to use the `in range` filter type right?

Comment: @Viqas - have update with steps to replicate

Answer (score 1):

As per docs -

> The floating filters for Text, Number and Date (the simple filters)
> are editable when the filter has one condition and one value. If the
> floating filter has a) two conditions or b) zero (custom option) or
> two ('In Range') values, the floating filter is read-only.

What this means is when you use floating filter to filter on column it will filter on one value only. If you want to add more than one filtering condition you will have to use the filter button that shows up a filtering menu.

Here is how your **'Rowing OR Fencing'** is interpreted when entered in floating filter.

[image]

The correct way would be to open the filter menu and add multiple filter criteria instead of typing in floating filter. In this case floating filter becomes read only.

[image]

More in the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filters/#provided-floating-filters)

Comment: Appreciate the time you made to answer this. Unfortunately i'd like to do this via typing manually, rather than having to click icons to activiate it. Additionally, the popup only allows 2 joins, i would like many more for example rowing OR fencing OR swimming

Comment: why don't you implement your custom filter which accept comma separated values and handle the filtering the way you want.